# Amazon AWS, create a SQL Server DBInstance and database

Tags: .net, sql-server, amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-rds

Is it possible to create a SQL Server database with Amazon AWS, while creating a database instance?

I'm using .NET Core with Amazon AWS SDK and instantiating `CreateDBInstanceRequest` object I cannot set the value for "DBNAME" parameter when I choose to create a SQL Server database.

So, when I create a database instance for SQL Server there is no database created.

Who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you can do that using cloud formation template and that would be much more reliable for your scenario. Below JSON has all the parameters required for you:

```
{
  "Type" : "AWS::RDS::DBInstance",
  "Properties" : {
      "AllocatedStorage" : String,
      "AllowMajorVersionUpgrade" : Boolean,
      "AssociatedRoles" : [ DBInstanceRole, ... ],
      "AutoMinorVersionUpgrade" : Boolean,
      "AvailabilityZone" : String,
      "BackupRetentionPeriod" : Integer,
      "CACertificateIdentifier" : String,
      "CharacterSetName" : String,
      "CopyTagsToSnapshot" : Boolean,
      "DBClusterIdentifier" : String,
      "DBInstanceClass" : String,
      "DBInstanceIdentifier" : String,
      "DBName" : String,
      "DBParameterGroupName" : String,
      "DBSecurityGroups" : [ String, ... ],
      "DBSnapshotIdentifier" : String,
      "DBSubnetGroupName" : String,
      "DeleteAutomatedBackups" : Boolean,
      "DeletionProtection" : Boolean,
      "Domain" : String,
      "DomainIAMRoleName" : String,
      "EnableCloudwatchLogsExports" : [ String, ... ],
      "EnableIAMDatabaseAuthentication" : Boolean,
      "EnablePerformanceInsights" : Boolean,
      "Engine" : String,
      "EngineVersion" : String,
      "Iops" : Integer,
      "KmsKeyId" : String,
      "LicenseModel" : String,
      "MasterUsername" : String,
      "MasterUserPassword" : String,
      "MaxAllocatedStorage" : Integer,
      "MonitoringInterval" : Integer,
      "MonitoringRoleArn" : String,
      "MultiAZ" : Boolean,
      "OptionGroupName" : String,
      "PerformanceInsightsKMSKeyId" : String,
      "PerformanceInsightsRetentionPeriod" : Integer,
      "Port" : String,
      "PreferredBackupWindow" : String,
      "PreferredMaintenanceWindow" : String,
      "ProcessorFeatures" : [ ProcessorFeature, ... ],
      "PromotionTier" : Integer,
      "PubliclyAccessible" : Boolean,
      "SourceDBInstanceIdentifier" : String,
      "SourceRegion" : String,
      "StorageEncrypted" : Boolean,
      "StorageType" : String,
      "Tags" : [ Tag, ... ],
      "Timezone" : String,
      "UseDefaultProcessorFeatures" : Boolean,
      "VPCSecurityGroups" : [ String, ... ]
    }
}
```

For reference you can always go to [AWS DOCS - AWS::RDS::DBInstance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html)

For Specific to .NET core, you can check the `RDS_DB_NAME` parameter and the reference Document [Deploy .NET RDS Instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_NET.rds.html). But [API_Operations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_Operations.html) do not have the parameter to create database directly because APIs are mainly for managing the AWS objects and not specific to handle underneath one of the objects because that would be considered as application level work.

Furthermore, I checked in the Powershell commands which are basically built on top of DOT NET only. It clearly have the parameter to create a Database as `-DBName` while creating the Database Instance. Reference link for Powershell command [New-RDSDBInstance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/New-RDSDBInstance.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Ranadip Dutta. But It's wrong for me. Like the documentation you posted say (I had already seen it before writing here) the dbname parameter for sql server is " Not applicable. Must be null.". I use that paramer for creation of dbinstance + database for mysql and postgres. And for them it works perfectly. But for sql server it doesn't work and beacuse of that I have write here.  
I solved my problem anyway, using entity framework.

Comment: Good to know that. You can post your answer with details so that it would be helpful for other community users @Franzkom